# I am having problems with changing the color of text that is within a div

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events

```
addNavBarEventListners();

function addNavBarEventListners() {
  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("navbar").length; i++) {
    item = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")
    item[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", navItemMouseEnterAction);
    item[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", navItemMouseExitAction);

  }
}


function navItemMouseEnterAction(event) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  this.style["boxShadow"] = "0 0 20px #999999";
  this.style.color = 'black';

}

function navItemMouseExitAction(event) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  this.style["boxShadow"] = "0 0 0px #999999";
  this.style.color = 'white';
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you want, what you did and what doesn't work. Posting only the code is not enough

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
let navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');

Array.from(navLinks).forEach(navLink => {
    navLink.addEventListener("mouseenter", navItemMouseEnterAction);
  navLink.addEventListener("mouseleave", navItemMouseExitAction);
})

function navItemMouseEnterAction() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    this.style["boxShadow"] = "0 0 20px #999999";
    this.style.color = 'black';
}

function navItemMouseExitAction(event) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  this.style["boxShadow"] = "0 0 0px #999999";
  this.style.color = 'white';
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: red;">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Instead of sleecting `navbar` select all `nav-links`.

**EDIT:**
Your code didn't work because you were selecting `.navbar` class which stands in the beginning of the `nav`, what you want to select is actually the `.nav-links` which are presented on `<a>` tag.

Here is a bootstrap navbar sample code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

More about about Bootstrap navbars can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

You were selecting the `<nav>` itself instead of `.nav-links` that was your mistake!

The rest of the code looks fine! I would just change the `document.getElementsByClassName('..')` inside for loop and declare it out, so that you dont have to reassign another variable inside the loop, so your code would look something like this:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');

for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
...
}
```

Comment: i have tried to use your code in my web page and it wont work either . but i can see that it works in the code snippet

Comment: show us your html we can give you some hints, it must be some class name that is missspelled or something like this, i have edit the answer to clarify you why your code wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for (i = 1; i < document.getElementsByClassName("navbar").length; i++)
```

to:

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("navbar").length; i++)
```

Comment: that still will not work to change the color of the text within the div

Answer (score 0):

In your addNavBarEventListners(); function, you have assigned variable i value of 1 in for loop i.e:
for (**i = 1;** i < document.getElementsByClassName("navbar").length; i++)
Change the value of variable i to 0.

Comment: that still will not work to change the color of the text within the div. .All elements are assign correctly

Comment: @shadowFox I guess selecting the navbar was the mistake I was making. By the way Francisco has given the correct answer. I learned through that too.